# SQL query to return GET() mm-yyyy -1 month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query below but I'm afraid it will not work when the year turns 2012. Any help would be fantastic.

```
SELECT distinct Month(GetDate())-1,Year(GetDate()) FROM myybl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()),105),7)
```

The formatted output for today would look like:

```
09-2011
```

If you want two separate columns:

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())) AS MONTH,
       DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())) AS YEAR
```

Output:

```
MONTH   YEAR
    9   2011
```

Comment: Why did someone give this answer a -1? I thought that this answer directly addressed the problem in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) [Month],
                YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) [Year]
FROM myybl
```

Comment: that wont work because i dont want 1 year ago, just 1 month ago

Comment: The -1 on the year only takes one month away from GETDATE not one year.  That will account for January.